# Text highlighted in Word, saved to PDF; how to search for HIGHLIGHTED items?

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-acrobat, text-formatting, highlighting

I have a large docx file with highlighted text. When the file is converted to PDF, is there a way to search for originally-Word-highlighted text?

Am using Adobe Acrobat X Pro and want to be able to search within the Pro version (not install a Reader just for this purpose).

## Update

Let's try this again. I want to find text based on the HIGHLIGHT attribute. If it's not highlighted, then it's not of interest.

If the text was highlighted with Acrobat, then you can instruct Acrobat to find highlighted text. But if it was highlighted in Word then converted to PDF, then--as best I can tell--Acrobat will not "see" the highlighting.

So, how do you make the highlighting visible to Acrobat so that Acrobat can search it?

Comment: Search for it from the PDF reader.

Comment: @harrymc - thank you for your quick reply. I edited my post to clarify that I want to use my Pro version to search for that text. I searched for an answer before I posted my original question, followed the instructions I found. As best I could tell, the only way to search for highlighted text was to highlight with the Acrobat tool in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I know for sure in the Google Chrome PDF reader upon pressing F3 it will bring up a dialog where you can search for words. Not sure about Adobe Acrobat but I can check it now.

**EDIT:**
Press Ctrl + F and search for the text in the highlighted text and click "Next". If the string exists in the PDF, it should bring you to the highlighted text or the word(s) you entered. If it does not bring you to the highlighted text the first time, press "Next" again until you find the Highlighted Text in the document.

Comment: it's not the text I'm looking for, it's the highlighting. I tried to edit my original question to make this more clear. In the meantime, I marked your comment as helpful because you genuinely tried to assist and didn't mark down my question without comment. StackExchange could use more participants like you.

Comment: Thanks, dude. I am not the best with PDF stuff but I tried my best. Hope it helps in some way!